# Win32::Daemon::State() does not return the state

Tags: perl, winapi, perl-module

Consider this skeleton code from Dave Roth's "Win32 Perl Scripting: The Administrator's Handbook":

```
use Win32::Daemon;
Win32::Daemon::StartService();
while( SERVICE_STOPPED != ( $State = Win32::Daemon::State() ) )
{
   if( SERVICE_START_PENDING == $State )
   {

     # Initialization code
     Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
   }
   elsif( SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING == $State )
   {

     Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_PAUSED );
     next;
   }
   elsif( SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING == $State )
   {

     Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_RUNNING );
     next;
   }
   elsif( SERVICE_STOP_PENDING == $State )
   {

     Win32::Daemon::State( SERVICE_STOPPED );
     next;
   }
   elsif( SERVICE_RUNNING == $State)
   {
     #Add code here to perform whatever work the service must accomplish
   }
   sleep(5);
}
Win32::Daemon::StopService();
```

The function `State()` can be used to *set* the status of the service (as is done in the above code snippet), and also to *return* the service's state at the current instant. However, when I try to print out `$State`, *numerical values* - I've seen 0, 1 and 4 so far - are what I get.

I have been unable to find any material that suggests that these states are constants defined as 0, 1, etc. anywhere. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try printing the value of SERVICE_RUNNING()...  they're not strings they're numbers; see inside https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-Daemon-20131206/constant.cpp

Comment: So they are! Thanks a ton, got it.

Comment: @optional : Thanks to your tip, I've identified what numbers most of the states correspond to. However, `$State` stubbornly returns 0 - which does not seem to correspond to any defined state. Any idea why?

Comment: [`GetConstantName`](https://metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-Daemon-20131206/constant.cpp#L189) seems to indicate that 0 is returned for `SERVICE_CONTROL_USER_DEFINED`.

Comment: I get SERVICE_CONTROL_USER_DEFINED          => 4144, zero probably means no_error or service_not_ready; see my "answer" for more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get `SERVICE_CONTROL_USER_DEFINED          => 4144,`.  Zero seems to have a few possible meanings

```
NO_ERROR                              => 0,
SERVICE_BOOT_START                    => 0,
SERVICE_NOT_READY                     => 0,
```

So its probably not [SERVICE_BOOT_START  0x00000000  A device driver started by the system loader. This value is valid only for driver services.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682450%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So it probably means its SERVICE_NOT_READY or NO_ERROR :)
See https://api.metacpan.org/source/JDB/Win32-Daemon-20131206/test/DumpConstants.pl

And also

```
#!/usr/bin/perl --
use Win32::Daemon;
use Data::Dump qw/ dd /;
dd( {map{ my $v = eval { $_->() }; $_ => defined $v ? $v : qq{EEP($v): $@}; } @Win32::Daemon::EXPORT});
__END__
{
  NO_ERROR                              => 0,
  SC_GROUP_IDENTIFIER                   => "+",
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_DEVICEEVENT            => "EEP(): Goto undefined subroutine &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD at .../site/lib/Win32/Daemon.pm line 123.\n",
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE  => 32,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_NETBINDCHANGE          => 16,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_PARAMCHANGE            => 8,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE         => 2,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT             => 64,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_SESSIONCHANGE          => 128,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN               => 4,
  SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP                   => 1,
  SERVICE_AUTO_START                    => 2,
  SERVICE_BOOT_START                    => 0,
  SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING              => 5,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE              => 3,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_DEVICEEVENT           => 11,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_HARDWAREPROFILECHANGE => 12,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_INTERROGATE           => 4,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDADD            => 7,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDDISABLE        => 10,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDENABLE         => 9,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_NETBINDREMOVE         => 8,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_NONE                  => -1,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_PARAMCHANGE           => 6,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE                 => 2,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT            => 13,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN           => "EEP(): Goto undefined subroutine &AutoLoader::AUTOLOAD at .../site/lib/Win32/Daemon.pm line 123.\n",
  SERVICE_CONTROL_RUNNING               => 4160,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_SESSIONCHANGE         => 14,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN              => 5,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_START                 => 4112,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP                  => 1,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_TIMER                 => 4128,
  SERVICE_CONTROL_USER_DEFINED          => 4144,
  SERVICE_DEMAND_START                  => 3,
  SERVICE_DISABLED                      => 4,
  SERVICE_ERROR_CRITICAL                => 3,
  SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL                  => 1,
  SERVICE_ERROR_SEVERE                  => 2,
  SERVICE_FILE_SYSTEM_DRIVER            => 2,
  SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS           => 256,
  SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER                 => 1,
  SERVICE_NOT_READY                     => 0,
  SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING                 => 6,
  SERVICE_PAUSED                        => 7,
  SERVICE_RUNNING                       => 4,
  SERVICE_START_PENDING                 => 2,
  SERVICE_STOP_PENDING                  => 3,
  SERVICE_STOPPED                       => 1,
  SERVICE_SYSTEM_START                  => 1,
  SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS             => 16,
  SERVICE_WIN32_SHARE_PROCESS           => 32,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_1                   => 16384,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_10                  => 536870912,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_2                   => 32768,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_3                   => 4194304,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_4                   => 8388608,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_5                   => 16777216,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_6                   => 33554432,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_7                   => 67108864,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_8                   => 134217728,
  USER_SERVICE_BITS_9                   => 268435456,
}
```

Comment: SERVICE_NOT_READY seems right, logically. :) Thanks a lot!